# Copy cell content to another sheet without loosing the content after cell deletion from the original sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to copy merged cell ("A4:H4") from sheet1 to sheet2("A4") but when i delete the merged cell from sheet1 it is geting deleted from sheet2 as well.
Is there any way if i delete the merged cell in sheet1 to keep the copied to Sheet2 content?

```
Sub baCopyNameOfHotel()
Sheet1.Range("A4:H4").Copy Sheet2.Range("A4")
End Sub
```

Comment: A simple `Sheet2.Range("A4").Value = Sheet1.Range("A4").Value` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Sub baCopyNameOfHotel()

Sheet1.Range("A4:H4").Copy 
Sheet2.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: It is still not working.
When i delete Sheet1 ("A4:H4"), Sheet2 ("A4") is getting also deleted.

Comment: something else is going wrong with your code. Firstly, specify the workbook & worksheets names. if the problem exist share your code.

Comment: Yes thanx pal it was a code that followed. Now it is just perfect. Thanx